# SQL Union All return "blank" record if null

Tags: sql-server

I have a list in excel that I'm trying to populate with data from our database. I need to pull the data in the same order it's listed in the query, so I'm using `UNION ALL` to do this.

However, some of the records in the union'ed selects are empty, so my line numbers in the resultset are getting messed up. Sorry the query is a bit complicated, I can't make it much simpler

```
select * from (select top 1 fundid as fundid, fundname, effectivedate from fundnamehist where fundID = '83' order by effectivedate desc) as tbl2
union all select * from (select top 1 fundid as fundid, fundname, effectivedate from fundnamehist where fundID = '173' order by effectivedate desc) as tbl3

... --a few hundred lines like the one above, generated in excel
```

So in this example, if result of the inner select for the `FundID` `173` returns
no results, I would only get one result instead of two. Instead, I'd like it to return *something*, like a row like `0, "", 1900-1-1` instead of nothing. My total query comes up about 400 lines shorter than i want it.

How can I do this?

I tried adding `ISNULL()`s around everything both in the "inner" select and the "outer" select but that didn't work.

"inner" select `ISNULL`s

```
select * from (select top 1 isnull(fundid,0) as fundid, isnull(fundname,'') as fundname, isnull(effectivedate, '1900-1-1') as effectivedate from fundnamehist where fundID = '83' order by effectivedate desc) as tbl2
```

"outer" select `ISNULL`s

```
select isnull(fundid,0) as fundid, isnull(fundname,'') as fundname, isnull(effectivedate, '1900-1-1') as effectivedate from (select top 1 fundid, fundname, effectivedate from fundnamehist where fundID = '83' order by effectivedate desc) as tbl2
```

(Note that this is a one-time process and I'm not really looking for any sort of optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41068/35665

A bit tedious, but I had to do another `UNION ALL` in the subquery:

```
...
union all 
    select  fundid, fundname, effectivedate from 
        (select top 1 fundid, fundname, effectivedate from fundnamehist where fundID = '173' order by effectivedate desc 
            union all select null,null,'1900-1-1' 
            where not exists 
            (select top 1 fundid as fundid, fundname, effectivedate from fundnamehist where fundID = '173')
        ) as tbl3
```